# How can i define the file path when opening workbook?

Tags: excel, windows, vba

I have a macro that opens a workbook (each time a different one) and imports data from it. But when I activate it, the standard path is to my documents. How can i define a file path to a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to change the default directory for choosing a file you would use:

`ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)`

However, if you're looking for some way to open a specific filepath, you would have to use a `FilePickerDialog`, assign a `String` to that user input, then use something like:

`[StringVarName] = Application.GetOpenFilename`

If you post your code with your attempt at fixing the issue, we would be able to better assist.